# Совочок, совок, шуфелька, сміттярка = абсолютні синоніми?

Tags: синоніми, іменники

До речі, чи можна вважати абсолютними синонімами слова совочок, совок, шуфелька та сміттярка, але в межах літературної мови? Адже часто їх використовують. У СУМі-11 подаються значення лише [совочок](http://sum.in.ua/s/sovochok), [совок](http://sum.in.ua/s/sovok), [сміттярка](http://sum.in.ua/s/smittjarka), однак щодо останнього, то подається у значенні професії, а не інструмента для збору сміття.Щодо синонімів, нічого не вказано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [Лексиконі львівському](http://slovopedia.org.ua/101/53409/1067011.html)  знаходимо:

> **смітярка** 
>   1. смітник (ст): Рушив дрібним трухцем в обхід до кухні, кінчиком парасолі відслонив фіранку в миснику, кинув оком до шафи, заглянув до смітярки (Керницький)
>   2. лопатка для сміття; **совок** (ср, ст): В руці тримала смітярку, і цією смітяркою вона поплескувала тепер по плечі прибулого, обійнявши його цілою силою рамен та повиснувши на його шиї (Лисяк)||**шуфелька, шуфлі**.

В іншій словниковій статті в [Лексиконі львівському](http://slovopedia.org.ua/101/53409/1067011.html)  знаходимо:

> **шу́флі** (шу́фля) 1. лопата (ср, ст)2. лопатка для сміття; **совок** (ср, ст)|| = **смітярка**.

Отже, **шуфелька, смітярка** – діалектизми, **совочок** – пестливе до **совок** – нормативне. А всі вони синоніми.